# Can you programmatically alter a queue's "dead letter" handling in a Java embedded broker?

Tags: java, multithreading, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

### Background

At a high level, I have a Java application in which certain events should trigger a certain action to be taken for the current user.  However, the events may be very frequent, and the action is always the same.  So when the first event happens, I would like to schedule the action for some point in the near future (e.g. 5 minutes).  During that window of time, subsequent events should take no action, because the application sees that there's already an action scheduled.  Once the scheduled action executes, we're back to Step 1 and the next event starts the cycle over again.

My thought is to implement this filtering and throttling mechanism by embedding an in-memory ActiveMQ instance within the application itself (I don't care about queue persistence).

I believe that JMS 2.0 supports this concept of delayed delivery, with delayed messages sitting in a "staging queue" until it's time for delivery to the real destination.  However, I also believe that ActiveMQ does not yet support the JMS 2.0 spec... so I'm thinking about mimicking the same behavior with time-to-live (TTL) values and Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) handling.

Basically, my message producer code would put messages on a dummy staging queue ***from which no consumers ever pull anything***.  Messages would be placed with a 5-minute TTL value, and upon expiration ActiveMQ would dump them into a DLQ.  ***That's*** the queue from which my message consumers would actually consume the messages.

### Question

I don't think I want to actually consume from the "default" DLQ, because I have no idea what other internal things ActiveMQ might dump there that are completely unrelated to my application code.  So I think it would be best for my dummy staging queue to have its own custom DLQ.  I've only seen [one page of ActiveMQ documentation which discusses DLQ config](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html), and it only addresses XML config files for a standalone ActiveMQ installation (not an in-memory broker embedded within an app).

*Is it possible to programmatically configure a custom DLQ at runtime for a queue in an embedded ActiveMQ instance?*

I'd also be interested to hear alternative suggestions if you think I'm on the wrong track.  I'm much more familiar with JMS than AMQP, so I don't know if this is much easier with Qpid or some other Java-embeddable AMQP broker.  Whatever Apache Camel actually is (!), I believe it's supposed to excel at this sort of thing, but that learning curve might be gross overkill for this use case.

Comment: +1.  Excellent question excellently written.  It's not every day you see a question like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you're worried that Camel might be gross overkill for this usecase, I think that ActiveMQ is already gross overkill for the usecase you've described.

You're looking to schedule something to happen 5 minutes after an event happens, and for it to consume only the first event and ignore all the ones between the first one and when the 5 minutes are up, right?  Why not just schedule your processing method for 5 minutes from now via [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) or your favorite scheduling mechanism, and save the event in a `HashMap<User, Event>` member variable.  If any more events come in for this user before the processing method fires, you'll just see that you already have an event stored and not store the new one, so you'll ignore all but the first.  At the end of your processing method, delete the event for this user from your `HashMap`, and the next event to come in will be stored and scheduled.

Running ActiveMQ just to get this behavior seems like way more than you need.  Or if not, can you explain why?

EDIT:

If you do go down this path, don't use the message TTL to expire your messages; just have the (one and only) consumer read them into memory and use the in-memory solution described above to only process (at most) one batch every 5 minutes.  Either have a single queue with message selectors, or use dynamic queues, one per user.  You don't need the DLQ to implement the delay, and even if you could get it to do that, it won't give you the functionality of batching everything so you only run once per 5 minutes.  This isn't a path you want to go down, even if you figure out how.

Comment: Yup!  My first attempt was an effort to use a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, exactly as you describe.  The problem is that I also need a way for subsequent events to check the pending queue, and NOT add additional task for a given user if that user already has a task pending.  Before `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` places tasks on its queue, it wraps them within a private nested class wrapper.  That nested wrapper type isn't even visible outside of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`... and even if it were, it doesn't expose the wrapped object that I originally passed.  (1 of 3)

Comment: So while embedding ActiveMQ may seem like overkill, my alternative would be to write my own custom alternative to `ScheduledThreadPoolExector`... which I believe is even MORE overkill!  I spent a couple of hours trying this.  (2 of 3)

Comment: Also, using a real MQ broker gives me some room to grow in the future.  If this application gets to a point where I want to run multiple instances of it in a cluster, then I can move the ActiveMQ broker from an embedded approach to a separate standalone installation... with minimal changes to my application code.

Comment: UPDATE:  Oh, I missed the part about "and save the event in a member variable".  That actually could be a viable solution, provided that I have a mechanism to drain that member variable when a task is pulled from the pool.  I'll think about it.  (Thanks!)  However, I'm still curious about how to do it with a message broker, for the purposes of future scalability that I described previously.

Comment: OK, so you can have a (single) pending task per user, rather than just one for the system?  It still seems like a `HashMap<User, Event>` would let you figure out whether an event is currently pending for the user, without all the overhead of ActiveMQ.  Granted, it doesn't handle clustering if the same user is being processed on multiple nodes in the same cluster, but that would be a problem for your implementation with ActiveMQ as well, so that's not an argument for either approach.

Comment: Correct.  However, a limitation of that approach is that I would have to manually drain from the HashMap when a task is pulled from the thread pool queue.  I could make that part of the thread logic itself, but that's sorta brittle.  Gets into concurrency issues to synchronize (maybe use a `ConcurrentHashMap`?), and runs the risk of leaving a user in a stuck state if an uncaught exception occurs before the Map is drained.

Comment: Also, while there of course would be SOME changes required if I moved from an embedded broker to a standalone broker... those changes would be minor compared the "`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`-with-`ConcurrentHashMap`" approach, which would require a complete re-write altogether if I moved to a clustered environment.

Comment: Between the two, I think implementing a custom, separate, DLQ for this is far more likely to be brittle and prone to unexpected behavior in the face of exceptions.  Yes, you'll want to use a thread-safe HashMap, and yes, you'll want to think about what you want to happen if a new event arrives for the user while your processing method is in the middle of running, and yes, you'll need to have proper exception handling.  All of this seems way easier than trying to do something very non-standard in ActiveMQ using code that may not be thoroughly tested because no one ever uses it.

Comment: I did not read the whole conversation as I was writing an answer, but that is pretty much what I came up with. And I find it quite simple.

Comment: To run in a clustered environment, you'll need to pin the processor for a given user to a single machine in the cluster to avoid having two machines read two messages and do the processing for a user at the same time.  (If you aren't afraid of two machines processing a given user's events at the same time, then the approach I've suggested will work just fine.)  If you believe that events could happen on all machines but need to get funneled to only the one machine processing for a given user, then you're right that you do need ActiveMQ or something similar.  (Part 1 of 2)

Comment: But if only one machine will be generating events for a given user and the same machine will be processing them, then you haven't gained anything with your message broker over the in-memory approach.  So your approach is a win only in the scenario where multiple machines generate messages for a user but only one of them is allowed to process them.  If you're not 100% sure that's your scenario, I wouldn't go down this path, because it feels like you're implementing a more-complicated scenario in order to handle a what-if scenario that may never come or where your solution may not be needed.

Comment: BTW, if you want a slightly-less-brittle way to handle tracking if a processing event is currently scheduled, you can store the `Future` instead of the event object in your `HashMap`, and then check the state of the `Future`.  If it's finished, you know you need to schedule and store another one.  You'll still need appropriate synchronization, but you wouldn't have to manually remove events from the `HashMap` when they're done processing.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is keeping track of the pending actions in a concurrent structure and use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to execute them:

```
private static final Object RUNNING = new Object();
private final ConcurrentMap<UserId, Object> pendingActions = 
    new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);


public void takeAction(final UserId id) {
    Object running = pendingActions.putIfAbsent(id, RUNNING);  // atomic
    if(running == null) {                // no pending action for this user
        ses.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doWork();
                pendingActions.remove(id);
            }
        }, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Camel this could be easily achieved with an [Aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) component with the parameter `completionInterval` , so on every five minutes you can check if the list aggregated messages is empty, if it's not fire a message to the route responsible for you user action and empty the list. You do need to maintain the whole list of exchanges, just the state (user action planned or not).